# Caffeine cache in multiple aws instances, how to invalidate them?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a beanstalk application which has multiple instances. In each application we are getting some data from DynamoDB. As records in DynamoDB are changes less frequently, we are caching the data from dynamoDB in local caffine cache with TTL of 15 min. However when the data on dynamoDB is changed the data in caffine cache should be evicted. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways. One way would be to **stream** events from DynamoDB to  a **lambda** function. When the lambda detects new data it can run **SSM Run Command** for your EB instances. The Run Command would clear all the required Caches.